# updating kafka dependency in camus is causing messages not read by EtlRecordReader

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, camus

In my project camus is used for long time and it is never get updated.
The camus project uses kafka version 0.8.2.2. I want to find a workaround to use kafka 1.0.0.

So I cloned the directory and updated the dependency. When I do that the Message here requires additional parameters [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/camus/blob/updated-dependencies/camus-etl-kafka/src/main/java/com/linkedin/camus/etl/kafka/mapred/EtlRecordReader.java#L232-L233).

As given in the github link above, the code compiles but the messages are not read from the kafka due to the condition [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/camus/blob/updated-dependencies/camus-etl-kafka/src/main/java/com/linkedin/camus/etl/kafka/mapred/EtlRecordReader.java#L237).

Is it possible to update the kafka dependency along with appropriate data constructors of `kafka.message.Message` and make it work.

Comment: You might want to see if Confluent 4.x releases bundles Camus using newer Kafka clients, otherwise you can follow the Apache Gobblin upgrade guides

Comment: @cricket_007 - Is Kafka-connect-hdfs (https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-hdfs/index.html) opensource or proprietary tool?

Comment: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs